# laravel, добавление sql в конструктор запроса, left join с условием

Tags: sql, laravel

Имеется некоторый запрос. В него внесена модификация, суть которой в том, чтобы произошел left join на основе 2х полей, но второе поле использовалось только если оно не NULL.
На sql эта часть запросы выглядит так:

```
left join `stores_remains`  on 
IF(`products`.`color_id` IS NULL, 
`stores_remains`.`parent_id` = IFNULL(products.parent_id, products.id) ,
`stores_remains`.`parent_id` = IFNULL(products.parent_id, products.id) 
              AND `stores_remains`.`color_id` = `products`.`color_id`)
```

В конструкторе запроса я попробовал такой вариант:

```
$query->leftJoin('stores_remains', function ($join) {
   $join->on(DB::raw("IF(`products`.`color_id` IS NULL, 
    `stores_remains`.`parent_id` = IFNULL(products.parent_id, products.id) ,
    `stores_remains`.`parent_id` = IFNULL(products.parent_id, products.id) 
     AND`stores_remains`.`color_id` = `products`.`color_id`)"));
                });
```

Но в $join->on() нужно указывать 3 параметра, из-за этого в запросе автоматически добавлялось  = `` , что вызывало ошибку.
Вопрос в том как правильно вписать данный запрос в конструктор запроса laravel?

Comment: а вы попробуйте начальный SQL-запрос без `IF` переписать как это обычно делают ( а-дя `(x is null and .... ) OR (x is not null AND ...)` `). потом уже с ларавелем разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально, цель задачи была в том, что бы сделать сортировку по полю *total_remains* , но из-за *null* в *color_id* часть записей некорректно джойнилось в итоге в *total_remains* у некоторых записей так же был *null* (что не соответствует действительности).

Свою задачу я решил следующим образом:

```
$query->leftJoin('stores_remains', function ($join) {
        $join->on('stores_remains.parent_id', '=', DB::raw('IFNULL(products.parent_id, products.id)'));
        $join->on('stores_remains.color_id', '=', 'products.color_id')
              ->whereNotNull('products.color_id');
                            });
$query->leftJoin(DB::raw('stores_remains AS t2'), function ($join) {
       $join->on('t2.parent_id', '=', DB::raw('IFNULL(products.parent_id, products.id)'))
             ->whereNull('products.color_id');
                            });
```

т.е. 2 раза left join одной и той же таблицы для полей с null и без.

Сортировку же сделал так:

```
$query->orderByRaw("COALESCE(stores_remains.total_remains, t2.total_remains) DESC");
```